# Visualising pandas pivot table into bar chart based on colour in column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have created a pivot table on my df using the following code:
 `pivot =pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Description', 'ColorID'],values=['Turnover'],aggfunc=np.sum)`

This has produced a pivot table with 128 rows as sample shown here:

```
                 Turnover    
Product Colour                               
t-shirt red        1550                   
USB     blue       23560                   
pen     white      50057
```

I can simply use `df.plot(kind='bar')` to visualise this in a chart but I am trying to switch the x axis so that it is vertical (due to large amount of products) and I also want to colour the bar chart for each product based on the colour in the pivot.

Is it possible to do this using a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Question not so clear. Lets try:

Unstack and plot

```
df.unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image]

or use seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
df=df.reset_index()
sns.barplot(x="Colour", y="Turnover", palette=["red", "blue", "grey"], data=df, ci=None)
```

[image]

As per your comments, you could try:

```py
import seaborn as sns
df = df.reset_index()
sns.barplot( x="Turnover", y="Product", hue='Colour', data=df, ci=None)
```

[image]

Comment: The seaborn code is similar to what I want, however the x axis should be turnover and y should be product. I would then like the colour of the bar chart for each product to be picked up from the colour column - is this possible? Thanks

Comment: If I got you right, see the edits. Thanks

Comment: This is almost right but the colour of the bar is random as opposed to what is stated in colour column. Is it not possible to do this? thanks

Comment: Unless we use pellet, I do not know how to automatically pick colour. The tradion on the forum is, if assisted you atleast upvote befor asking for more. You dont have to vote if not satisfied though